# C++ Static Declaration

Tags: c++, class, static, namespaces, member

I am trying to declare a static variable in console.h and define it in console.cpp.  the line calling the variable is:

```
     ok = CheckIoEditMinMax(0,Console::_tabsize, curpos, 0, insert,
     20-Console::_tabsize,20, offset) && ok;
```

I have know been able to pass it, but the compiler doesn't like the way I am doing it. For example I have declared it like this:

```
/*Edited*/
namespace cio{
  class Console{ 
    public:  
    static unsigned int _tabsize; //Under public so it can be reached by the main.
                                  //inside the console class in cio namespace
    };
}
```

And then defined in the cpp file like this:

```
/*Edited - Also No it is not Const */
namespace cio{
   unsigned int Console::_tabsize = 4;
}
```

But the compiler still doesn't like this and is saying this:

```
console.cpp:8:32: error: âunsigned int cio::Console::_tabsizeâ is not a 
                  static member of âclass cio::Consoleâ
```

I don't Know why its doing this or even where to figure it out.  Also it is a little bit odd that the compiler would say this don't you think?

Comment: Put a little more context around you code. The class, namespace, etc.

Comment: Well, compiler clearly says that `_tabesize` is not a member, maybe there is reason for that?

Comment: try to remove 'static' in cpp, just "unsigned int Console::_tabsize = 4;". Also, make sure that tabsize is a field of the class Console (I presume Console is a class; if it is a namespace, try "namespace Console {unsigned int Console::_tabsize = 4;} " inside cpp

Comment: I'd say @CaptainOblivious spotted the bug!

Comment: sorry static in the cpp was a mistake

Answer (score 2):

Only the declaration of the member variable needs to include the `static` specifier.

```
struct Foo
{
    static int value_;
};

// static specifier cannot be used here. 
int Foo::value_ = 1;
```

In this case if `_tabsize` does not change you can declare it as `const` and assign a value to it in the class definition. If you do not there is no need to provide a definition.

```
struct Foo
{
    static const int value_ = 1;
};
```